# Mass vector assets import Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector-graphics

Is there a way to import many vector svg images into project? Importing 30+ icons is kind of boring and rather stupid. Which script is Android Studio using to convert svgs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well in case anyone will be interested there are [online tool](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) and [offline .NET/Mono tool](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter) for mass import. The last one is more reliable and flexible. Or we can use [shell script](https://gist.github.com/deepankarb/e69de4373ebd7067e0fc).

Comment: You can use it for simple Vector assets, true. But for more complex images you should prefer the Android Studio implementation for this. I got issues with rotated vectors in the images for the convert from SVG to vector xmls, the result was a wrong produced image.

Comment: @KennySeyffarth agreed with you.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible in Android studio now. In the resource manager on the left side. Works great!

[image]

Comment: You saved my day, I had 20+ SVGs, it would be a pain to import them all one by one :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this link, it's really helpful :
https://svg2vector.com/

Just upload all your svg file (you can select multiple files) and download all drawable files. Copy to your Drawable project file and viola!