# Is there a way to bulk convert svg files using Android Asset Studio?

Tags: android, svg, android-drawable

I have a large number of svg files I want to convert to xml vector assets for Android.

The documented process is, for each file, File->New->Vector Asset.  Then choose the svg file, click Next then Finish.

Is there a faster way?   Maybe a bash comment to launch Asset Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927461/android-automate-svg-import/40931070

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mass vector assets import Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660212/mass-vector-assets-import-android-studio)

Answer (score 32):

The Resource Manager tool that was added in Android Studio version 3.4 can bulk import SVGs and convert them into vector drawables.

1. `Tools` → `Resource Manager`
2. Select the `Drawable` tab
3. Click the `+` button in the top left corner
4. Select `Import Drawables`

There you can select all the files you want to import at once.
More details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager).

Comment: With close to 100 vector icons to import at once, this saved me _a lot_ of time, thanks! Should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 12):

There are few Git projects which would help you achieve the bulk conversion of svg files to Vector Drawable supported by android.

1. <s>Juraj Novák's : http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/</s>
2. <s>[SvgToVectorDrawableConverter](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter)</s> original repo was deleted. But you could choose [one of the fork](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter/network/members) . Example: `svg2vd -i "\*" -o out --fix-fill-type`
3. For single conversion: [SVG to Vector Drawable Convertor online](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/)
4. Use [wrapper of original converter](https://github.com/ravibhojwani86/Svg2VectorAndroid) ported from Android Studio

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just for reference, here is the exact command I used.
`./svg2vd -i "D:\temp\SvgToVectorDrawableConverter_v1.4\climacons\*.svg" --inkscape "D:\\temp\\SvgToVectorDrawableConverter_v1.4\\inkscape\\inkscape.exe" -o out --fix-fill-type`

Answer (score 4):

download [this jar file](https://github.com/ravibhojwani86/Svg2VectorAndroid/blob/master/Svg2VectorAndroid-1.0.jar) and use it as in the bellow example

```
java -jar C:\Users\dan\Downloads\Svg2VectorAndroid-1.0.jar C:\Users\dan\Desktop\svgs_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep `Svg2VectorAndroid.jar` and the folder that having all the Svg file in same folder and then open `cmd` and go to that folder path where you put your jar and source folder and then execute the command

```
java -jar Svg2VectorAndroid.jar <source folder name>
```

and press enter. Now you can get your all xml file in source folder with folder name `ProcessedSVG`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link, it's really helpful :
https://svg2vector.com/

Just upload your svg file (you can select multiple files) and download all drawable files. Just copy to your Drawable project file and viola!

Comment: FYI, (maybe b/c it's the free version) this tool doesn't optimize and separate paths as well as the Android Studio tool. Most of my files show the "very long vector path" performance warning