# How to import multiple vector drawables to Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I used https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ to convert 50+ SVG's to XML as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191242/1181261). Now I have a .zip containing all the XML files. Where do I put them to be able to use them in Android Studio?

I know I can import one by one but that's what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: This tool (svg2android) has been deprecated. It now says that you should use Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio.

Comment: it doesn't allow for multiple svg at once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the xml files in drawable folder, and you will be able to retrieve them using R.drawable.names

Comment: I did not have `res/drawable` folder under so I created it, works fine. Thanks.